# SQLAzure databases (3) are disappeared. how to comunicate that to Microsoft?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Few minutes ago 3 DB on one SQLAzure sever disappeared and the management console tell me that there are problems to retrieve information about the databases on specific SQL Server of West Europe region.

In the "Support" section we are not able to send a tecnical question, only billing question.
But this is NOT a QUESTION, this is a SIGNAL !!!! (Microsoft is becoming a wall of gum?)

Any one have any way to inform MS that theirs 99.95% up-time services are off???

Many thanks in advance.
Have nice week-end.
Davide.

Comment: Hey Davide, This question is off-topic here, please read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't see a "Technical" option in the drop down on the support form you'll likely see below the form something that says "Your Support Plan: Free - billing support only
Your current plan does not include technical support from Microsoft.".  This means that you haven't purchased support, which comes with the web incident submittal.  It will also have a link to the following page https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/plans/, which describes the support levels.

Sadly, at the free support level there doesn't even seem to be a way to tell them that something seems wrong other than to [post to the forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/windowsazureplatform,azuremarketplace,windowsazureplatformctp).  If you are a MSDN Subscriber there is a link on that same support forum that leads you off to a different form which I believe will start an online chat.

In addition the service dashboard gets updated when issues are discovered and they have information to post.  Just because something isn't showing up yet doesn't mean that they aren't aware of an issue.